# Javascript does not load on alternate URL unless it is in a file

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing

I have a server at http://reallycomplicatedservername42342390 on an internal corporate network.

I have added a nice freindly URL at http://friendlyurl

The issue is, I had javascript inline that simply is not executing on the friendly URL unless it is in an external file. It runs fine on the server name as is.

I have made sure there are no absolute URL references in the JS that could cause it to fail, I have added an `alert()` and `console.log` at the head of each `<script>` tag to see if the JS is being entered into AT ALL, and nothing fires.

However, put the exact same code, completely unaltered into a .js file and reference it, and it all works fine.

I've never run across this, and my website isn't broken, but could someone explain this phenomena so I never do it again?

Comment: Could we possibly have the JS code?

Comment: I can't answer why you're having that happen, but for the sake of semantics, I believe that its best the script run externally. Maybe if you showed the code we could see if its in the wrong place or something.

Comment: That's weird, because a URL change shouldn't have any effect on inline scripts. Like others said could you provide the JS code and we could see if there are any problems?

Comment: It sounds like a cross domain issue to me, but it's hard to say without having more details (are the urls coming from the same domain, how are you referencing the script, etc.).

Comment: The only domain related call is an AJAX call, but I have a function which returns the URL for the POST based on an examination of the window.location.href.

I also am baffled. I'll post the code in a few.